# Error de navegación de manera local

Tags: firefox, https

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

En la empresa tenemos hosteadas varias aplicaciones a las que accedemos desde el dominio `www.empresa.com/aplicacion`

El tema es que de manera remota, las paginas andan bien, pero cuando estoy en la red interna de la empresa, las paginas son redireccionadas por https.
He probado sacarlo de la lista hsts, pero el problema persiste.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opcion 1: Si estas usando apache configura el htaccess para que haga una redirección de https a http

Opcion 2: Configura tu proxy para que no haga la redirección a https

Opcion 3: Configura un certificado de seguridad, se puede hacer gratis con https://certbot.eff.org/

Saludos,

Comment: Un poco tarde mi respuesta, pero, uno gracias por contestar.Dos, el problema resulto ser el dns local. Gracias.